# Field is validated when loosing focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm doing validation of a textbox with RequiredFieldValidation.

I want it to validate the textbox only when a button is clicked, not when textbox loses focus.

Now, every time when I click anywhere else on a page it shows an error message.

Here is a code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
      <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" Text='<%#Eval("CustEmail") %>' />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
          ValidationGroup="grpEmail" 
          ErrorMessage="Must enter Email Address" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <asp:Button Text="Update Email" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="UpdateEmail" 
           ValidationGroup="grpEmail"
           CausesValidation="true"  
           Visible="true" runat="server"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I just need it to be validated when button is clicked. That's it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute CausesValidation of the Textbox to false should do the trick.